# How to get a frequency table with 2 variable in rows and 1 in column?

Tags: sas

With SAS I'd like to get a frequency table like this:

```
varA  varB       varC
             varC1  varC2
varA1 varB1     n1     n2
varA1 varB2     n3     n4    
varA2 varB1     n5     n6    
varA2 varB2     n7     n8
```

where varA/B/C are my variables, varA1, varA2, varB2, etc. are the values of my variables, and n1, n2, n3, etc are the frequency.

With

```
Proc freq data=myfile ORDER=DATA;
tables varA * varB * varC / norow nocol NOPERCENT NOCUM missing;
run;
```

I get separate tables for any value of varA.

Comment: Is this for reporting or do you want a SAS data set like this?

Comment: @draycut Reporting is enough, thanks. If it easier to create a dataset, it's OK also the dataset. What is easiest for you is ok.

Comment: @draycut I've found a solution with proc TABULATE.

Comment: Ok. Just added a possible solution. Feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it in PROC TABULATE

```
data have;
input a b c;
datalines;
1 2 2
2 3 1
3 1 2
2 2 1
3 1 2
;

proc tabulate data =  have;
   class a b c;
   table a*b, c*n='';
run;
```